# package oracle.adfmf.application does not exist

Tags: java, compiler-optimization, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I have been gettin errors like that :

```
annotations are not sopported -in source 1.4
```

then looked my jdk version, I saw 1.4. To increase jdk compability version, I had to change java se version from CVM_JDK to 1.6.0_24(default).

Although annotation erros disappeared, two errors come up like this :

```
Error(3,32):  package oracle.adfmf.application does not exist
Error(43,47):  cannot find symbol
```

says for this line;

```
public class LifeCycleListenerImpl implements LifeCycleListener
{
  public LifeCycleListenerImpl()
 {
  }

 /**
  * The start method will be called at the start of the application.
   * 
    ...
```

and,

```
import oracle.adfmf.application.LifeCycleListener;
```

How Im gonna do the right thing for both ? Which jdk version provides that ?

Answer (score -1):

**Edit (2016):** This is only valid for ADF Mobile in JDeveloper 11.1.2.3.0

**Edit (2018):** The fix is not to change the JDK version since it isn't supported

I assume you are talking about ADF Mobile?
If so, currently the JavaVM is based on the JavaME CDC spec, and is based on Java 1.4. Changing the JDK will only break things.

Comment: what i have to do exctly

Comment: How do I fix it then? Can you provide additional information on this issue?